# how to open one app from another app react-native android.?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying `React-Native-Linking` and `react-native-deep-linking` but doesnt work.

The following code run successfully only For Skype but if you open another App it doesn't work.

```js
const checkapp = () => {
  let url = "skype://app";
  Linking.openURL(url).catch(err => {
    if (err.code === "EUNSPECIFIED") {
      if (Platform.OS === "android") {
        AppInstalledChecker.isAppInstalled("skype").then(isInstalled => {
          if (isInstalled) {
            Linking.openURL("url");
          } else {
            console.log("is installed false");
            Linking.openURL(
              "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skype.raider&hl=en"
            ).catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
            });
          }
        });
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Platform Is Ios");
    }
  });
};
```

If any solution then give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 100% working for open all app from another app using `react-native-send-intent`.
>
> React Native Android module to use Android's Intent actions for opening third party apps.

Installation
`npm install react-native-send-intent --save`

Register Module >= 0.29 (in MainApplication.java) Adding only 2 lines

```
import com.burnweb.rnsendintent.RNSendIntentPackage;  // <--- import in MainApllication.java

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
  ......

  @Override
  protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
        new MainReactPackage(),
        new RNSendIntentPackage()); // <------ add this line to your MainApplication 
  class
  }

  ......

  }
```

Example / Open App in your react-native code

```
 SendIntentAndroid.isAppInstalled('com.medlife.customer').then((isInstalled) => {
            if (isInstalled) {
                SendIntentAndroid.openApp('com.medlife.customer').then((wasOpened) => {
                });
                console.log("is installed true");
            }
            else {
                Linking.openURL('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.medlife.customer&hl=en').catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
            }
        });
```

> I am opening 3rd party `Medlife` app from my app if you have need to open another app then only change `pacakage name` in `SendIntentAndroid.openApp('com.medlife.customer')`

[react-native-send-intent git hub example here](https://github.com/lucasferreira/react-native-send-intent)